# How do I compare strings ignoring case?

Tags: string, d, string-comparison

I need to compare two `string`s (and not ASCII-only) in D ignoring case. The obviously solution is:

`s1.toUpper() == s2.toUpper()`

But I want to avoid strings duplications or write one myself in favor of a possibily fastest native onde (if any).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From exactly 30 seconds looking up the online D reference at:

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html

I found `String.icmp`:

> **alias icmp = std.uni.icmp(S1, S2)(S1 str1, S2 str2) if (isForwardRange!S1 && is(Unqual!(ElementType!S1) == dchar) && isForwardRange!S2 && is(Unqual!(ElementType!S2) == dchar));**
>
> Compares two ranges of characters lexicographically. The comparison is case insensitive. Use std.algorithm.cmp for a case sensitive comparison. For details see std.uni.icmp.

```
< 0     s1 < s2
= 0     s1 == s2
> 0     s1 > s2
```

Comment: To be fair, I have enough experience, and with enough languages that I knew it had to be there and knew exactly what to look for. Also, the documentation is not very well designed, IMHO.

Comment: It happens to us all at times. For what it's worth, I just googled "d language", found dlang.org, clicked on the library reference link for the `String` class, then did a page search for "compare".